# Can't compile QtSerialPort in qt creator

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtserialport

I have downloaded qtserialport files from git and tried to compile it in qt-creator.
At first I tried "Build" option, but have tried "Run qmake" as well.

Both give me same result

> :-1: error: Failed to run: C:\Qt\Qt5.0.1\5.0.1\msvc2010\bin\syncqt.bat
>   -module QtSerialPort -mkspecsdir C:\Qt\Qt5.0.1\5.0.1\msvc2010/mkspecs -outdir C:/qtserialport-build-Desktop_Qt_5_0_1_MSVC2010_32bit-Debug C:/qt-qtserialport

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be working nowadays without any issues. We have fixed all the windows and qmake file related issues in the QtSerialPort build system.

Please try again with a later version.